# I have the Java edition of Minecraft on my windows 10, wondering if there is any way to show my coordinates. i have tried looking it up, nothing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have also tried going into my settings to look for an option that might help, and i have not found anything so far. could you help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Cordinates HUD Vanilla tweaks Datapack

Download here: https://vanillatweaks.net/picker/datapacks/

**A video showing it here:**

Comment: Welcome to arqade.se! take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. Nice first post, it's the first time I hear of this tool, and to me, it seems much easier to use than using the coordinates located within all the variables when using F3.

Answer (score 0):

in Java Edition, the best way to get your coordinates and other various information about your position and the block you are looking at, press F3 and if that does not work press Fn + F3. When you have opened the overcomplicated display, look for XYZ or Block. XYZ shows you position in centimeters or centiblocks. Block show your position in meters or blocks. These displays are in the left hand side of the display, and when you are done looking, press F3 or Fn + F3 again to exit it.